# Why was this post deleted?

Tags: support, moderation

Why was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668792/) deleted by [andrew-barber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/237838/andrew-barber)?

Comment: That question should be closed anyway...

Comment: Perhaps the user was spamming answers related to that product?

Comment: Many of this user's answers were deleted for plagiarism.

Comment: The user asks a question about how to read Outlook messages without opening Outlook. The answer suggests a library that uses Extended MAPI without starting Outlook. This is a a perfectly valid answer. One could also mention CDO 1.21 (which is no longer installed by Outlook or supported by MS) or Extended MAPI (which can be only used from C++ or Delphi).

Comment: That is a terrible question. I probably should be deleted.

Comment: @staticx You should probably be deleted? ;P

Comment: @hichris123: Ah crap lol

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: You should also mention that the answer that was deleted was a direct advertisement for your own product, which might explain in part why you're concerned that it was deleted.

Comment: Ouch, the burn it hurts

Comment: @Ken White: Yes, I do monitor posts that mention Redemption. And yes, I am concerned that posts mentioning Redemption are deleted. Why is this bad? Because Redemption is a commercial product? You seem to be a Delphi user (I am too); if an Embarcadero employee mentions Delphi in his post, will you delete it? I do not get this attitude towards commercial software. If it solves the problem that the OP is having, is the answer only allowed to mention free or open source products? Oh, and by this logic, should all Outlook questions and answers be banned? It is a commercial product after all.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: Because commercial products have to be purchased, and can't be used in open source products, and because it doesn't answer the question here at SO. But the reason I mentioned it is because you didn't disclose it in your question here, and it is relevant. The reception is different if you're saying "Why was this great answer deleted?" than it is if you had openly said "Why was this great answer that advertised my own commercial product deleted?". And no, I have no issue with a commercial product being mentioned, as long as the question is answered here first in such a way

Comment: (continued) that someone not willing (or able) to buy the product first, and then a mention of the commercial product as something that might also be a solution, but the commercial product shouldn't be the *only* solution offered, and it shouldn't be first. This isn't the "advertise your product for free* site; it's a knowledge base. There are many other sites where you can advertise. And if an EMBT employee answered, and then said "Our company's product can do this more easily. You can see here for info", it discloses the affiliation to the product ("our company's"). Your post here did not.

Comment: @Ken White: I have to disagree on "because it doesn't answer the question here at SO". The OP asks how he can access Outlook data without starting Outlook. If I were answering the question, I would mention that Outlook Object Model cannot be used since it starts outlook.exe and suggest
1. Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only). 
2. CDO 1.21 (no longer developed, supported or installed) 
3. Redemption (built on top of Extended MAPI and accessible from any language).

Comment: (continued): Since the question was tagged "C#", I imagine #1 is irrelevant. #2 is also out of the question, which leaves only #3. Which is what the reply mentions. I fail to see how it does not answer the question.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko: It doesn't answer the question here at SO because **it requires purchasing a commercial product**. It's the equivalent of someone asking how to accomplish a task on a Windows 7 machine, and someone posting an answer that says "Buy a Mac. Then in OSX, you can do it by...". Questions **asking for** product recommendations are off-topic at SO, and so is shilling a commercial product. Part of the reason for that is the spam potential ("our product does this". "Well, our product does that AND this". "Well, this third product does THAT and THAT and throws in THIS AND THIS").

Comment: No, the question does not ask "how do I do this using Outlook Object Model or a free library?". It asks how to do a particular task. Using your example, for a question like "how do I develop an iPhone app", an answer "buy a Mac and install XCode" would be perfectly fine.

Comment: (continued) But this has been debated here before (including by you, IIRC), and the majority of users have said no to commercial advertising in answers. None of this is relevant anyway; my initial comment was simply to point out that you had a somewhat concealed agenda in asking about this question.

Answer (score 15):

Because the initial version of the answer used code directly copied from [this page](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) without attribution. It is straight-up plagiarism.

A C# version was added later on, a trivial translation.

A quick check with the Google cache shows the user lost 1/3rd of their answers, it looks like this was one in a series of deleted posts. In the meantime the account has asked itself to be deleted (with a 'thank you' note to the moderator).

Comment: The "Thank You" note: "*Please delete me. I don't want to be member of StackOverflow. GOD Bless Andrew Barber and he is NICE moderator who is invest his time in deleting Answer which has up votes also.*" Obviously this user doesn't get it.